# How to limit user for login more than three times in this vb.net coding

Tags: vb.net

How can I modify the following code to limit a user to three login attempts?

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim Attemp As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "1" And TextBox2.Text = "1" Or
           TextBox1.Text = "2" And TextBox2.Text = "2" Then

            MsgBox("You are Now Logged In as User Rights", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Login")
            Form5.Show()
            Close()

        Else
            If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("No Username and/or Password Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
            Else
                If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("No Username Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                Else
                    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                        MsgBox("No Password Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Invalid Username And/Or Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something like `Attempt = Attempt + 1` just before the last `end if`. Then you can check `Attempt` variable in the first `if` with an `and`.

Comment: `If (Attempt < 3 And ((TextBox1.Text = "1" And TextBox2.Text = "1") Or
           (TextBox1.Text = "2" And TextBox2.Text = "2") )) Then ... ` is the first part. l already written the other part above.